# Mobile Devices with Office 365 With local exchange

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

Looking into Mobile Device Management for Office 365 however we use a local exchange vs exchange online.

Is this possible? can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As long as Autodiscover is setup properly for your domain, you should not have any issues. You can check setup at [testconnectivity.microsoft.com](http://testconnectivity.microsoft.com).